# Split value on array rust

Tags: rust

I need to split value of array like

```
let v: Vec<&str> = token.split("Bearer ").collect();
```

and log the value of the token the value is `Bearer eyJGciOiJSU` and I need to get only `eyJGciOiJSU`
when I print the `v[1]` to the log I got error index out of range, any idea?

Comment: Please write a [MRE] and check it exhibits your error. The [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) is a popular solution for this.

Comment: Also, if you just want to strip the prefix, look at [strip_prefix](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.strip_prefix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to assess without a minimal example, but this works on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4416b5152dd5d6b5a7cdb4fad008a1f7):

```rust
fn main() {
    let token = "Bearer eyJGciOiJSU";
    let v: Vec<_> = token.split("Bearer ").collect();
    println!("{}", v[1]); // prints "eyJGciOiJSU"
    
    let id = token.strip_prefix("Bearer ").expect(r#"Token ought to start with "Bearer""#);
    println!("{}", id); // prints "eyJGciOiJSU"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! one question , I need to get the `payload` eg `name` from the jwt token any idea how to do it?  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5362f057ecbb99fe783c6ecf8c9bddbf

Comment: this is the jwt example https://jwt.io/ , I need at the end to get the `  "name": "John Doe"` from the payload, could you please assist?
`

Comment: @JennyM You might want to have a look at [this example](https://docs.rs/jsonwebtoken/7.2.0/jsonwebtoken/fn.decode.html) from the jasonwebtoken docs. You should just need to replace the `Claims` struct with a struct that matches your payload type. I.e. something like `struct Payload { sub: String, name: String, iat: usize }`.